Template for a math exercise sheet with double line header and footer
I found this very nice exercise sheet

Where there is this double header line. I tried to do a template like this
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\headheight}{55.80002pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{54.90001pt}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\large \textbf{Analysis II} \hfill \textbf{SS 2019/2020}\\ \medskip
\normalsize Vorlesung: Prof. Dr. \hfill Vorlesung: Prof. Dr. } 
\fancyfoot[C]{page \thepage} 

\begin{document}

\vspace{-3cm} 
\hrule height 0.9pt  

\begin{center}
    \huge \textbf{Blatt XIV PÜ}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    Keine Abgabe
\end{center}

\section*{Exercise 1 (3 Punkten)}
Prove:

\begin{itemize}
    \item[(a)] $(A \cap B) \setminus C = (A \setminus C) \cap (B \setminus C)$
    \item[(b)] $(A \cup B) \setminus C = (A \setminus C) \cup (B \setminus C)$
    \item[(c)] $C \setminus (A \cup B) = (C \setminus A) \cap (C \setminus B)$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}

Here is a link to the original pdf-file. Note that there is also this fancyline at the bottom:

My try is not that good, I think the header is fine but I do not get how to do this double line. Can some one help me in this regard? Its just for personal usage, I am messing around with a few templates I like.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Section 17 of the fancyhdr documentation suggests to redefine \headrule (and \footrule) in such cases. The original definitions can be found in \f@nch@initialise:
  \def\headrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth\fi
      \hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth
      \vskip-\headrulewidth}}%
  \def\footrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\footrulewidth\plainfootrulewidth\fi
      \hrule\@width\headwidth\@height\footrulewidth}}%

The \hrule commands here define the line itself. \@height\hrulewidth resp. \@height\footrulewidth is the thickness of the line. I would suggest to use it for the height of the whole line construct and use some fraction of it for the first rule, some fraction for the second rule and some fraction for the distance between the rules:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% Not needed for more than a decade!
\setlength{\headheight}{55.80002pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{54.90001pt}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\large \textbf{Analysis II} \hfill \textbf{SS 2019/2020}\\ \medskip
\normalsize Vorlesung: Prof. Dr. \hfill Vorlesung: Prof. Dr. } 
\fancyfoot[C]{page \thepage}% use [R] if you want it right aligned instead of centered 

\makeatletter
  \def\headrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth\fi
      \hrule\@height.5\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth
      \vskip.3\headrulewidth
      \hrule\@height.2\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth
      \vskip-\headrulewidth}}%
  \def\footrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\footrulewidth\plainfootrulewidth\fi
      \hrule\@width\headwidth\@height.2\footrulewidth
      \vskip.3\footrulewidth
      \hrule\@width\headwidth\@height.5\footrulewidth
    }}%
  
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{1ex}% height of the whole line contruct with two lines in the page header
\renewcommand*{\footrulewidth}{1ex}% height of the while line contruct with two lines in the page footer

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \huge \textbf{Blatt XIV PÜ}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    Keine Abgabe
\end{center}

\section*{Exercise 1 (3 Punkten)}% Manual numbering is not LaTeX like. Better use titlesec to redefine \section
Prove:

\begin{itemize}
    \item[(a)] $(A \cap B) \setminus C = (A \setminus C) \cap (B \setminus C)$
    \item[(b)] $(A \cup B) \setminus C = (A \setminus C) \cup (B \setminus C)$
    \item[(c)] $C \setminus (A \cup B) = (C \setminus A) \cap (C \setminus B)$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}


Just a note: There are several packages for exercises available. Most of them support not only automatic numbering but also calculation of available points, separation of questions and answers etc.

Is it just me that the design reminds me a lot of a condolence card?
